# How to compare a string with the elements inside a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop, compare

I have an `array` which contains the data of classrooms and different oxygen readings at different time. So the user has to input the specific classroom and the time, and my program will print out the oxygen reading of that classroom at that time. However, I have an `error` where I cannot compare the `string array` with a `string`. Can someone help me please?

```
cout << "Please enter the classroom: ";
string classroom;
cin >> classroom;
cout << "Please enter the time: ";
string time;
cin >> time;
cout << endl;

string myData[6][13] = {
    { "EN10-5-56" , "500", "700", "2000", "1850", "2000", "800", "750", "2300", "1900", "1600", "750", "700" },
    { "EN10-5-65" , "550", "1600", "1700", "780", "1980", "700", "750", "2300", "780", "800", "650", "550" },
    { "EN14-5-83" , "600", "700", "2000", "1850", "2000", " 600", "650", "700", "200", "800", "750", "700" },
    { "EN14-5-69" , "900", "600", "1950", "780", "800", "590", "620", "760", "1900", "1890", "2000", "700" },
    { "EN18-5-112", "550", "1670", "2000" , "680", "900", "1500", "1800", "2500", "779", "800", "650", "650" },
    { "EN18-5-118", "800", "1890", "2300", "1850", "2000", "800", "750", "1700", "560", "1300", "1500", "850" },
}; // row x column (class x time)


// row x column
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // classrooms (row)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
    {
        if (myData[i] == classroom) // ERROR HERE
        {
            cout << myData[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Error C2679   binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion), at  (myData[i] == classroom).

And also how do I find use the input time to get the readings? Any idea??

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error C2679 binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: `myData` is not an array of `string`, so `myData[i]` is not a `string`, as you're attempting to use it in your `if` statement. It's an array of array of `string`. So you're comparing a `string` to an `array` of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

`myData` is a 2-dimensional array, but you're only providing a single dimension specifier.

`myData[i]` will give you an `array-of-string`, not a single `string` instance. You're using `i` for column, so you must also provide `j` for the row.

```
if( myData[i][j] == classroom ) {
    cout << myData[i][j] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! Then, can i ask how to use the time the user input, together with the classroom, to print out the reading?? thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Its a 2D matrix. You cannot access its element as `myData[i]`. You have to give both indexes.
Replace `myData[i]` with `myData[i][0]` where you are comparing it with `classroom`.
Replace `myData[i]` with `myData[i][j]` in if condition.

It should work now.

Comment: oh! thanks i forgot that my array need 2 indexes. opps!

Answer (score 0):

`myData` is not `1-dimensional array`, It is a `2-dimensional array`.

So, you have to try this way :

```
cout << "Please enter the classroom: ";
string classroom;
cin >> classroom;
cout << "Please enter the time: ";
string time;
cin >> time;
cout << endl;

string myData[6][13] = {
        { "EN10-5-56" , "500", "700", "2000", "1850", "2000", "800", "750", "2300", "1900", "1600", "750", "700" },
        { "EN10-5-65" , "550", "1600", "1700", "780", "1980", "700", "750", "2300", "780", "800", "650", "550" },
        { "EN14-5-83" , "600", "700", "2000", "1850", "2000", " 600", "650", "700", "200", "800", "750", "700" },
        { "EN14-5-69" , "900", "600", "1950", "780", "800", "590", "620", "760", "1900", "1890", "2000", "700" },
        { "EN18-5-112", "550", "1670", "2000" , "680", "900", "1500", "1800", "2500", "779", "800", "650", "650" },
        { "EN18-5-118", "800", "1890", "2300", "1850", "2000", "800", "750", "1700", "560", "1300", "1500", "850" },
}; // row x column (class x time)


// row x column
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // classrooms (row)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
    {
        if (myData[i][j] == classroom) // NO ERROR HERE
        {
            cout << myData[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```